# How to debug greenplum using gdb

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, gdb, distributed, greenplum

I need to use gdb to debug greenplum, the distributed version of PostgreSQL database. Now I have successfully installed greenplum and was able to use psql to run a sql. However, when I use gdb to debug it, it is difficult to get the code trace. It reports "no such file" frequently. I did not find useful documents online. Does anyone has related experience? Thanks.

For the greenplum database, I have one master node and two segment nodes.

In terminal A, I first use pg_backend_pid() on the master node to get the backend thread id.

```
[testDB=# select pg_backend_pid();
pg_backend_pid 
----------------
           9893
(1 row)
```

In a different terminal B, I then use gdb to attach to the backend process:

```
gpadmin@greenplum-mdw:/home/build/gpdb$ sudo gdb -p 9893
```

I can see the threads information by "info thre":

```
(gdb) info thre
  Id   Target Id                                   Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7fe0a51a7740 (LWP 9893) "postgres" 0x00007fe0a24d587f in __libc_recv (fd=11, buf=buf@entry=0x102db80 <PqRecvBuffer>, n=n@entry=8192, flags=flags@entry=0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/recv.c:28
  2    Thread 0x7fe08cee7700 (LWP 9894) "postgres" 0x00007fe0a194974d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
```

In terminal A, I run a sql through the psql interface:

```
[testDB=# select count(*) from customers;
```

In terminal B, I run the program by steps, but it says no such file or directory like this:

```
(gdb) n
29  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/recv.c: No such file or directory.
```

and this

```
(gdb) n
pq_recvbuf () at pqcomm.c:925
925 pqcomm.c: No such file or directory.
```

I want to look at function PostgresMain, so I did:

```
(gdb) b PostgresMain
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x87c860.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x87c860: file postgres.c, line 4590.
```

But after I run continue like this:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

It just never stop.

Comment: Is it open source? Do you have the debuginfo installed?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you, there is some reference on gdb over postgres: [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD)

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you show what *actual* command(s) you used to get "no such file".

Comment: I know how to use gdb over postgres, for greenplum, it is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that greenplum did not add -g and -ggdb flags when compiling. I added it and then it works.